# Memory leak in activity enter transition coordinator after shared element transition

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, shared-element-transition, sharedelementcallback

I'm having a problem with memory leak in `EnterTransitionCoordinator` while using shared element transitions. Below you can see the app structure:

[image: App structure]

It has 2 screens, first is an `Activity` with `DrawerLayout` and few `Fragment`s inside. One of them consists a list of photos and clicking specific photo triggers shared element transition to `Fragment` from `ViewPager` located in another `Activity`. I'm using custom `SharedElementCallback` when exiting and reentering these two `Activity`s for mapping a correct `View` for shared element transition. I based my code on this great blog post: https://android.jlelse.eu/dynamic-shared-element-transition-23428f62a2af

The problem is, that after swiping between `ViewPager`'s items, `Fragment`s are being destroyed, but the `View` used for shared element transition is being kept in `Activity`'s `ActivityTransitionState`, specifically in `EnterTransitionCoordinator`. The same when reentering to `Activity` with `DrawerLayout` and then opening another `Fragment`. References to `View`s used for shared element transitions are still kept int `Activity`s even though `Fragment`s were destroyed, which causes a memory leak.

My question: Is there a good way to avoid this memory leak?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that there's a method `clearState()` in `EnterTransitionCoordinator`, which should be called in `Activity.onStop()`. But since the `Activity` is not yet being stopped, `View`s from `Fragment`s are being leaked. As a temporary workaround, I'm clearing that state manually on `Fragment.onDestroyView()` by calling this method with reflection. Below you can see the code:

```
/**
 * Works only for API < 28
 * https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces
 */
fun Fragment.clearEnterTransitionState() {
    try {
        getActivityTransitionState()
            ?.getEnterTransitionCoordinator()
            ?.invokeClearStateMethod()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // no-op
    }
}

private fun Fragment.getActivityTransitionState() =
    Activity::class.java.getField("mActivityTransitionState", requireActivity())

private fun Any.getEnterTransitionCoordinator() = javaClass.getField("mEnterTransitionCoordinator", this)

private fun Any.invokeClearStateMethod() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        javaClass.superclass?.invokeClearStateMethod(this)
    } else {
        javaClass.invokeClearStateMethod(this)
    }
}

private fun <T> Class<T>.getField(name: String, target: Any): Any? =
    getDeclaredField(name).run {
        isAccessible = true
        get(target)
    }

private fun <T> Class<T>.invokeClearStateMethod(target: Any) {
    getDeclaredMethod("clearState").apply {
        isAccessible = true
        invoke(target)
    }
}
```

Comment: Its probably better not to do this.  If you're actually low on memory, the framework will destroy the previous activity, which will clear this up for you.  The only case where it may be a problem is if you have a single, very large allocation to make and need to avoid running OOM on it.  This would also break any animation on the back button.

Comment: @GabeSechan sure, I agree it's not the best way to fix it. Actually, it's not breaking any animation on back button since custom SharedElementCallback is set to map correct view for transition.